# How is the concept of symmetry being used in this question - Equal Flip Timer?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Question:

Brad and Chad both flip coins with probability $p$ of heads on each flip. Let $B$ be the event that it takes strictly fewer flips for Brad to get his first heads than Chad, $C$ be the event that it takes Chad strictly fewer flips than Brad to get his first heads than Brad, and $E$ be the event that it takes them an equal number of flips to obtain their first heads. Find the value of p such that P[E] = P[C].

Part of the solution:

By symmetry, we know that $ P[B] = P[C] $ as they are both flipping coins with the same probability of heads. Therefore, as we want all three terms to be equal, they all should have probability $ \frac{1}{3} $, as they sum to 1. In other words, we need to find a value $ p $ such that the probability both of them obtain their first heads at the same time is $ \frac{1}{3} $.

Using the concept of symmetry, why is $ P[B] = P[C] = P[E] = \frac{1}{3} $ ?

Comment: Because $~P(B) + P(C) + p(E) = 1,~P(B) = P(C), ~$ and it is required that $~P(C) = P(E) .$

Comment: @user2661923 thank you! Now that you have laid it out so simply, I feel a bit silly asking this question...